# Sign-in with Linkedin Spring Boot Rest api

Tags: java, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I can not sign-in with Linkedin. I see 401 error code. Please help me. My code:

```
  HttpResponse httpResponse = Request.Get("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json")
            .setHeader("Host", "api.linkedin.com")//
            .setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")//
            .setHeader("x-li-src", "msdk")//
            .setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + form.getToken())
            .execute().returnResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with your headers and for me the request works if I remove the "x-li-src" header. With "x-li-src" I get

```
{
    "errorCode": 0,
    "message": "Unable to verify access token",
    "requestId": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "status": 401,
    "timestamp": 1551696403376
}
```

Please also note that Linkedin announced that version 1 of their API will not work after 1 March 2019 (though it is still available as of 4 March 2019). You should migrate to version 2 of the API.

https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates